# Swift 4 conversion: Error cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with argument list of type(AvAudioChannelCount)

Tags: ios11, swift4

I am migrating my app to swift 4 ios 11 beta 4 version and i got below error, please help me out if any one has come across this problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
for channelIndex in 0 ..< Int(audioFormat?.channelCount) {
                let frameMemory = channelMemory?[channelIndex]
                memcpy(frameMemory, allSamples, Int(frameCount) * MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
            }

It is giving an error message in integer converstion  -
```

Int(audioFormat?.channelCount)

```
    The error message is cannot invoke initializer for type Int with an argument list of type(AVAudioChannelCount)
```

Comment: The error message must be **`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(AVAudioChannelCount?)'`**. Do not miss `?`. And your code does not compile even in Swift 3. (Though Swift 3 generates a better diagnostics message.) Just my curiosity, from what version of Swift/Xcode are you migrating? One more, what do you want to do when `audioFormat` is `nil`? Anyway this is a problem of Optional which exists in Swift before pre-1.0 betas. Have you studied about Optionals?

Comment: Thanks, OOPer.
I am Migrating swift 3.0 - 4.0, in my case audioFormat always a value. Yes, you are a right. the problem with Optionals.

Comment: How was your code in Swift 3.0? Or you are migrating your code which cannot be built with Swift 3.0?